# Draw scatter plot and set color based one categorial column in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("bj", 
"cq", "sh", "tj"), class = "factor"), area = c(1580.86, 1927.95, 
532.24, 613.09), price = c(9.51, 94.42, 10.77, 8.58), level = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I want to draw a scatter plot which `x` for `area` and `y` for `price`, at same time, the color of points only based on `level`, which means only two colors to distinguish `a` and `b`.

How could I draw this with `ggplot2`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code for that

```
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(df, aes(x = area, y = price, col=level)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = area, y = price, col=level)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = city))
```

[image]
**Data**

```
df=structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("bj", 
"cq", "sh", "tj"), class = "factor"), area = c(1580.86, 1927.95, 
532.24, 613.09), price = c(9.51, 94.42, 10.77, 8.58), level = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: If I want to add `city` to the points, I used `geom_text(aes(label = city))`, it seems not working.

Comment: I think it's better to use `geom_text_repel`.

Comment: Yea, modified the answer for future reference.